# Flatlist not smooth with lot of image per item

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I use a flatList to make my activity feed.
However, I have a problem with the fluidity of my list

Each item can render up to 80 static images of 25kb, each in an absolute view, I still have to play with the performance when I mount my components but when I scroll, if I have my 80 images per item, my list is absolutely not fluid!

However, when I check my rendering number, I have very few because I use PureComponent for my items.

I check the RAM, and everything looks good!

My UI and JS Threads are constantly at 60!

Could this be due to the number of views I see in "Perf Monitor" that goes up to more than 3000? If it's that, how do I fix it?

Hoping to have a solution,

Thank you

Viktor

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue , but after reading docs ive implemented the below :

> You can use the community packages (such as react-native-fast-image
>   from @DylanVann) for more performant images. Every image in your list
>   is a new Image() instance. The faster it reaches the loaded hook, the
>   faster your Javascript thread will be free again.

You should always use [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) for more images.

Hope it helps. Feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!

I already use FastImage to render each Image, I try to optimize to the maximum I had already seen this trick but unfortunately it hasn't changed anything!

Comment: ohh sorry, umm, then its a very common and weird issue in react native. Will look for any answer

Comment: Hey, 

I noticed that when my application was in release mode, there were few or no lags !
However, in my emulator/device in debug mode (js debugger disabled), it's so laggy that I don't even know how to work anymore!

Is it something to do with static images maybe?

Comment: thats the case with debug mode ,  prod / release mode is always faster. but try it out first on all devices to see if it lags

Answer (score 0):

I had issue in my android version. I set resizeMethod="resize". This gave me massive performance boost.
I was loading lot of large images in section list and FlatList. Using resizeMethod as resize resolved my issue, and scroll is buttery smooth after this.